# Having multiple choices, but need single xsl:value-of when a certain condition is met

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an xml file which have multiple similar elements with similar child-elements. E.g.

```
<root>
    <elem>
        <condition>A</condition>
        <value>111</value>
    </elem>
    <elem>
       <condition>B</condition>
        <value>555</value>
    </elem>
    <elem>
        <condition>A</condition>
        <value>222</value>
    </elem>
</root>
```

One of these elements contain a value I need to extract in xsl. The value must be identified by a condition stated in another element in the element child nodes.
Lets say the condition is 'B' and I need the value of that element '555'.

I know how to get the right value in the xml editor XPath I use (Rinzo - Eclipse) =>

```
/root/elem[condition='B']/value
```

But I fail to get (any) value when I try to get it in xsl =>

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/elem[condition='B']/value"/>
```

The value in the xsl will be in a single element, so can not use for-each loop.
Imho the original xml is badly formed, but I can not help with that.

So the question is, how do I get that value in an xsl file, using xsl:value-of?

Comment: Do you have any namespaces in your XML document?

Comment: Good point about the namespace. I did not realize the entire XML file was not being shown. So we cannot see the XSL or the XML file really. I am going to delete my answer. It is probably that there is a default namespace.

Comment: There is no namespace. The actual file "root" is as shown with the example (the example simplified of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot see the rest of your XML or XSL but your value-of statement works as shown.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="/root/elem[condition='B']/value"/>
</xsl:template>
```

That works and returns: 555

As **Flynn1179** points out, in the comments, your XML probably contains a default namespace and that is not being take into account in the XPATH.

Try adding the namespace to the XPATH either inline (replace http://yournamespace-here.example.com with the actual URL):

```
/*[namespace-uri()='http://yournamespace-here.example.com' and local-name()='root']/*[namespace-uri()='http://yournamespace-here.example.com' and local-name()='elem'][condition='B']/*[namespace-uri()='http://yournamespace-here.example.com' and local-name()='value']
```

or by giving it a prefix in your XSL

```
xmlns:myPrefix="http://yournamespace-here.example.com"
```

and then adding that to your XPATH

```
/myPrefix:root/myPrefix:elem[condition='B']/myPrefix:value
```

Comment: `[condition='B']` too should be written `[myPrefix:condition='B']`, right?

Comment: Default namespaces do not apply to attributes, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting

Comment: There is no namespace. The actual file "root" is as shown with the example (the example simplified of course). Everyhting else works. I have about a hundred of other value-of statements and lots of conditions. This in the only value-of statement that needs condition in it's select clause.

Comment: The xsl file has the 'template' part. Other parts work and I end up with xml files that can be of several hundred rows. Only this particular value is missing. Will try again as seems this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: After I used another file as xsl source I had the value correctly in the result, using the exact same value-of statement I had before. Maybe I had added typo in the original file somehow or something like that. Sorry for the inconvenience on this. The example I posted in the first place seems to be correct after all. Accepted the answer of 'Jayson Lorenzen'.